# How to implement correct cube frustum culling

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, frustum, culling

I'm trying to implement frustum culling for my directx application. Each geometry in my application is surrounded by a bounding volume, which I'm trying to use to determine whether it's inside the view frustum or not. The bounding volume is a cube that guarantees to completely cover the geometry. To implement cube culling I used the [rastertek frustum culling tutorial](https://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut16.html), but I think there is a bug.

It's implemented as:

> CheckCube checks if any of the eight corner points of the cube are
> inside the viewing frustum. It checks if any one of the corner points are
> inside all 6 planes of the viewing frustum. If it does find a point
> inside all six planes of the viewing frustum it returns true,
> otherwise it returns false.

But it's also possible for the cube to be inside the frustum when neither of the corner points is. I've made a sketch - for simplicity assuming top-down view and orthographic projection. **In red is the view frustum, in blue the bounding volume**:

[image]

As you can see the bounding volume is inside the frustum, but neither of the corner points are. This causes bugs where objects appear and disappear and I haven't been able to solve this yet. I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction on this.

Comment: You are right. A simplified way to achieve frustum culling is to do it the other way around: If there is a frustum plane where all cube vertices lie on the outer side, then the cube is outside of the frustum. Otherwise, consider it as inside. This may give a few false positives (outside cubes classified as inside) but this can usually be accepted to keep the culling check simple and fast.

Comment: Recent editions of Luna's _Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX_ include a chapter on frustum culling. Would be worth comparing Luna's approach to the Rastertek algorithm.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks, that solves the issue and fits my needs. Can you post it as answer?